# No changes in database schema were found when using migration:generate

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

Basically, I've made a mess.
I have a project built in nestjs and mysql, and utilizing migrations to manage structure changes and insert dummy data.
At some point some generated migrations files have been deleted before versioning them in the git, I've tried to revert and re-generate them, but it produced errors because it can't find the files specified in the migration table, so deleted the table from the db, and now nothing works.
On generate it just logs `No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command`

I've followed all the guides here on stack, reverted all the changes from git, deleted the whole node_modules folder, changed the migration folder, rebuilt, set synchronize true/false, but nothing works.
At this point, the project is some steps back, but for typeorm it's still at the most advanced version.
Where's the folder that traces the changes?
Or anyway, what else can I do?